# Obtener ciertos datos segun fechas de una tabla con datos acumulativa con determinado valor

Tags: sql, table, pivot, mssql

Tengo una tabla sql con dos campos Fecha y Val (0 y 1).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y solo obtener las fechas iniciales y finales de los valores "1" de la columna **Val**. Quedando de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta que realizas encaja perfectamente con un problema conocido en Sql como "**finding gap and islands**".

Existen varias maneras de resolver este problema.

```
Create table dbo.FindingIslangds (Fecha date, val bit)
go
Insert into dbo.FindingIslangds (Fecha, val)
values
('20190212',0),
('20190213',0),
('20190214',0),
('20190215',0),
('20190216',1),
('20190217',1),
('20190218',1),
('20190219',0),
('20190220',0),
('20190221',0),
('20190222',0),
('20190223',0),
('20190224',1),
('20190225',1),
('20190226',1),
('20190227',1),
('20190228',1),
('20190301',0),
('20190302',0),
('20190303',0),
('20190304',1),
('20190305',1),
('20190306',0),
('20190307',0),
('20190308',0);
GO
```

Para el escenario las fechas se insertan en formato ISO (yyyyMMdd).

Lo primero que requiere esta solución, es disponer de un Sql Server version 2012 o superior, ya que se hace uso de la función de ventana [LAG](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lag-y-lead-siguiente-y-anterior/)

```
WITH c
     AS (SELECT *,
                CASE
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, LAG(Fecha) OVER(PARTITION BY val
                         ORDER BY Fecha, 
                                  val), Fecha) = 1
                    THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                END AS grp
         FROM dbo.FindingIslangds t),
     c2
     AS (SELECT *, 
                SUM(grp) OVER(PARTITION BY val
                ORDER BY fecha ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grupo
         FROM c),
     c3 AS (
     SELECT MIN(Fecha) AS fechainicio, 
                MAX(Fecha) AS fechafin, 
                val
         FROM c2
         GROUP BY val, 
                  grupo
                  )
     SELECT Format(c3.fechainicio,'d','es-es') as Inicio,
            Format(c3.fechafin,'d','es-es') as Fin
     FROM c3
     WHERE val = 1;
```

[image: Resultado]

El funcionamiento es el siguiente:

En el conjunto **c** establecemos una columna llamada **grp**, que nos indica si la diferencia en días de sobre la fecha de la fila actual, es igual a 1 entonces sabemos que es un valor consecutivo, por tanto le ponemos al flag **grp = 0**, sino se cumple, quiere decir que hay un salto por tanto ponemos un **grp = 1**.

[image: Cte1]

En el segundo conjunto **c2** sumamos, los unos del flag grp, obteniendo grupos de cambios. Así tenemos ***"paquetes"*** de información por cada cambio realizado.

[image: paquetes]

En el tercer conjunto **c3**, extraemos el valor mínimo y máximo de fechas por cada "**paquete**". Aquí ya habríamos podido terminar la query, realizando una restricción por el val = 1.

[image: Resultados c3]

Por último, le damos el formato esperado a la salida.

Ahora bien, al no haber puesto la definición de tú origen de datos, y solo una imagen de la cual no se puede extraer mucha información, si en tú origen de datos, las columnas no son date, tendrás que realizar un cast (col as date), para que la solución sea funcional.

[Tablas de expresión común correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Consulta adicional, en el caso que el formato sea este "2019-02-12 17:33:23.000" ¿cual sería la modificación que se debería hacer?

Comment: En el primer conjunto "c", en todos los sitios donde se menciona la columna, haces un cast (fecha as date)